# MethodCallExpression orderby

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to build a lambda query using expression trees to make it generic to use throughout an application. I based my initial attempt on the code found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx). I altered the code so that it does a Compare to return 100 entities whose LastName is just before the searchText, like so:

```
TEntity entity = entitySet.FirstOrDefault();
string searchName = entity.GetType().GetProperty("SearchName").ToString();
searchText = "Baker";
int records = 100;

IQueryable<TEntity> queryableData = entitySet.AsQueryable<TEntity>();
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), searchName);
var body = Expression.LessThan(Expression.Call(
    typeof(string), 
    "Compare", 
    null, 
    Expression.PropertyOrField(param, searchName), 
    Expression.Constant(searchText)), 
    Expression.Constant(0));

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, param);

MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { typeof(TEntity) },
    queryableData.Expression,
    lambda);

var data = entitySet.AsQueryable<TEntity>().Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(whereCallExpression).Take(records);
```

The code above works, it returns 100 entities from the database that reside just before my searchText, but they are the wrong entities because they are not in order in the entitySet. So, I need an OrderBy clause in my Expression tree so that I get "Azure", Axel, Avis", etc.

I tried this:

```
 MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "OrderByDescending",
    new Type[] { typeof(TEntity), typeof(TEntity) },
    whereCallExpression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, string>>(param, new ParameterExpression[] { param }));

var data = entitySet.AsQueryable<TEntity>().Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(orderByCallExpression).Take(records);
```

I get the error "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Expression of type MyEntity' cannot be used for return type 'System.String'"

**StackTrace:**

at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters)

at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)

at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable`1 parameters)

So, I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367353/adding-a-method-call-to-a-linq-expression-whilst-remaining-an-full-expression/1379693#1379693) and tried this:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> sortExp = l => l.SearchName);

MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "OrderByDescending",
    new Type[] { typeof(TEntity), typeof(string) },
    whereCallExpression,
    sortExp);
```

I get the error "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The specified type member 'SearchName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

I think the problem is that the SearchName property is a string that holds the name of the field on the entity that I want to OrderBy. I tried:

```
l => (string)l.GetType().GetProperty("SearchName").GetValue(SearchName);
```

but that gives me the error: "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

**TEntity** is based on EntityObject

**SearchName** is a property of type string on TEntity that holds the name of a field in the DB.

**entitySet** is of type `ObjectSet<TEntity>`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update and Solution**
I found code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367353/adding-a-method-call-to-a-linq-expression-whilst-remaining-an-full-expression/1379693#1379693) that got me thinking in a different direction. Here is the code that works for ordering by SearchName:

```
var type = typeof(TEntity);
var property = type.GetProperty(searchName);
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
var orderByExp = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);

MethodCallExpression orderByCallExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "OrderByDescending",
        new Type[] { typeof(TEntity), typeof(string) },
        whereCallExpression,
        Expression.Quote(orderByExp));                                   

var data = entitySet.AsQueryable<TEntity>().Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(orderByCallExpression).Take(records);
```

Comment: I tried the code you pasted and it worked for me.  Can you provide 1) the stacktrace for the error, and 2) a self-contained reproduction?

Comment: This is my first post on StackOverflow, so bear with me. I added the relevant part of the stacktrace to the post. I'm not sure that I can provide a self contained example yet. Did you use the first orderByCallExpression and it worked?

Comment: Ahh, this looks like an error with using Linq to Entities, not in the construction of the expression itself (which I tested with Linq to Objects).   Are you sure SearchName is a field on the entity within your data model?

Comment: SearchName is a property added to TEntity, but it is not a field in the data model. It is a string property that holds the name of a field in the data model. So, if the developer wants to search on the LastName field, they put "LastName" in the SearchName property.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @tster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that I used for the SearchName not being a field in the table.

```
if (entity.SearchName == "LastFirstName")
{
    //// Construct Expressions to hold the propert values
    Expression lastNameExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "LastName");
    Expression firstNameExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "FirstName");

    //// Construct a String.Concat method. 
    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });

    //// Combine the LastName + FirstName for the compare
    MethodCallExpression combinedExp = Expression.Call(methodInfo, lastNameExp, firstNameExp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If SearchName is a field not stored in your database, you should ignore it in your entity model, either using [ignore] attribute or the `this.Ignore(t => t.Property);` fluent API.

Comment: Hi Rogelio, I need to handle the SearchName properties. If the SearchName is set to LastFirstName (a property on the entity that is populated from 2 fields in the table), I break those into their respective fields to build the expression. Thanks, for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a predicate like

```
l => l.GetPropertyValue(l.SearchName) == "MyString"
```

where `GetPropertyValue` designates the value of the field named by `SearchString`. Even if you construct an expression tree that contains this logic, EF will not be able to translate it to SQL. SQL is statically typed. You cannot access a column by a dynamic name.

Work around that. For example, construct an expression of the form:

```
l =>
  (
   l.SearchName == "MyField1" ? l.MyField1 :
   l.SearchName == "MyField2" ? 2.MyField1 :
   l.SearchName == "MyField3" ? 3.MyField1 :
   null
  ) == "MyString"
```

or

```
l =>
   l.SearchName == "MyField1" && l.MyField1 == "MyString" ||
   l.SearchName == "MyField2" && l.MyField2 == "MyString" ||
   l.SearchName == "MyField3" && l.MyField3 == "MyString" ||
   false
```

Comment: Yes, I had to manually construct the expression tree from the fields indicated by the value in the SearchName property. i.e SearchName has a value of LastFirstName, I constructed the expression using the real field names of LastName, then FirstName.

Comment: @Laz5 what does that mean? Did this answer resolve the issue for you? Or do you have follow up questions?

Comment: I resolved the issue when I posted the Update and Solution portion above in the initial question. I created an Expression for each field. So for LastFirstName, I had 2 expressions that contained LastName and FirstName that I used when I called the Concat Method to construct the searchstring.